# Accessing the camera instance online

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I just want to know, is it possible to open camera instance and take a picture online.

in other words, if i have an app has an access to the internet can i create a button to open the camera and take a picture while i'm being online?

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead just use the [`toImage()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-toImage) function of all views (including a [WebView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView)) that Titanium provides. This will give you a screenshot.